# how to put menubar below the banner

Tags: css

My menubar show on my banner... It stacks.
Can you tell me how to put menubar below the banner?

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
        * { margin:0 auto;
            padding:0;
            }
                html { background:#ffffff; }
                body{
                         width:1600px;
                         height:800px;
                         overflow:auto;
                         background:#ffffff;
                        }
                div#menu {
                                margin:40px 0 0 95px;
                                text-align:center;
                                position:absolute;
                                }
                div#menu span {
                                font-size:22px;
                                padding-left:14px;
                                }
</style>

<?php
//include('menu.php');
include('menu_inc.htm');
?>      
<img src="bannersketch.png" border="0">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason it is stacking is you have `position:absolute;`.  Try putting the `<img>` tag above the php include and remove the absolute positioning and see if that helps.